# How to differentiate tax code per SAP module?

Tags: percentage, sap-erp, tax

Is there a way to make the same tax code percentage vary according to the sap module you use it in? like tax code `vz` 19% in module MM, tax code `vz` 0% in module SD.

maybe there is a certain transaction that offers the respective settings?

thanks

Comment: For what do you need it? Taxes are defined by state laws and may vary for product groups, but I have problems to get a tax law that make differences for a SAP module.

Comment: It´s about understanding why there are different tax percentages for the same tax code on the input and output side. I have got that case and try to rebuild in order to understand.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to have one tax code both for purchase and sales.  For each tax code, you can see a field "Tax type" which will differentiate whether it is intended for sales or purchase and ofcourse, all your financial postings will also happen based on this.